# actionbar support v7 android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

**IDE**: Android Studio

1. Create new project
2. Copy .jar of appcompat to by /lib/
3. Set dependencies in project settins
4. Add compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" to build.gradle
5. Add follow code:

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       actionBar.setTitle("hello");
   }
   ```

AND... Nothing. Get next error:

```
"Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':MyApplication'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyApplication:_DebugCompile'.
  > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+.
    Required by:
        MyApplicationProject:MyApplication:unspecified"
```

How to fix? What i forget to do?

Comment: did you download the Android Support Repository? I don't think you need the JAR.

Comment: I have installed support repository :(

Comment: Have you added the library dependency in the project settings? I mean, not only add the library in the library category. You have to add it in the project dependencies as well.

Answer (score 7):

you need to install the support repository

> 3.Select the Android Support Library item.
>
> Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the
> Android Support Repository item instead.
> http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the the library instead of copying it.

Also include:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```